# Binary Search can't find target number

Tags: java, binary-search

I can't understand why my binarySearch method can't find the desired target number. For example main method, I used an 3-length array (1,2,3) and the target number, 3. In the binary search method, at one point, the start and end variable will equal 2(2, representing the index value). In my code, I have a condidtion that if start and end were to equal each other, it would check if the source[mid] would equal 2,which it should. It would then return true. But I don't understand Why it isn't returning true.

```
public class Searches {

public static boolean binarySearch(int[] source,int start, int end, int target)
{
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;


    if (start == end)
    {
        if (source[mid] == target) return true;

    }



    if (target < source[mid])
        {
            end = mid - 1;
            binarySearch(source,start, end,target);
        }
    else if (target > source[mid])
        {
            start = mid + 1;
            binarySearch(source, start, end, target);
        }
    else return true;




    return false;
}



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] b = {1,2,3};
    System.out.println(binarySearch(b,0,b.length-1, 3));    
}

 }
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: You never actually use the result of the recursive call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this appears to be homework:

*Remove* the `return false` at the end of the function and then *fix* the compiler error *without* adding another line of code.

After making the changes it will be apparent what Quirliom's comment means.